# 4th moment greater or equal to 2nd moment

Tags: probability

I'm trying to proof something, I've taken some steps and it eventually comes down to the fact that $\mathbb{E}(X^4) \geq \mathbb{E}(X^2)$ where X is any random variable. I'm now wondering if this is even true, and if so how i could proof it.

I've tried writing the expectation of $X^4$ as an integral and using integration by part twice to get something with of the form $A-B+12\mathbb{E}(X^2)$ but that didn't get me anywhere.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is clearly false. take for example the pdf of x is the uniform distribution from 0 to 1

Answer (score 1):

This clearly not true as the inequality is not dimensionless. 
Let me give you an informal reasoning. Formal proof will require some kind of $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

The left hand side has units U^4 and the right hand side has units U^2 where $U$ is the unit of $X$. To see what this means, let $Y_1=X/10$, $Y_2=X/100$, $Y_3=X/1000$ and so on, i.e. $Y_n =X/{10}^n$. Each $Y$ is just $X$ except unit of $Y$ is ${10}^n$ times the unit of $X$. i.e. If $X$ is some length measured in millimeters, $Y_1$ is measured in centimeters, $Y_2$ in decimeters etc. If the unit is chosen so high that $|Y|<1$ with very high probability. Note that for $|Y|<1$, $|Y|^4 < |Y|^2$ so $E(Y^4) < E(Y^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that if X < Y then E(X) < E(Y). As long as your X values don't belong to (-1,0) or (0,1), then your statement is true.